# Is "went to it himself" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, reflexive-pronouns

> Danny moved eagerly toward the box of beer, but Mark stopped him and
> **went to it himself**.

Hi. I wrote this sentence and thought it sounded OK, but then I did a search on Google and found out that ["went to it himself"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went%20to%20it%20himself%22&sxsrf=ALeKk03RTLBgWUW9M0acFdJxf0KL8WqV6w%3A1618914657625&ei=Ya1-YL_ZJYjUsAf_94eoCw&oq=%22went%20to%20it%20himself%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CAghEBYQHRAeUN8hWMM8YItCaAFwAHgAgAGGAYgBhgOSAQMzLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj_jduIz4zwAhUIKuwKHf_7AbUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) only had 6 hits, so my question is if it's not correct and natural or maybe it's just the construction of the sentence that is unusual? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct and natural and the construction of the sentence is not unusual.